# how can i resolve this error "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\jiten/.aws/credentials'" in windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Just installed awscli, and having issues with my configuration.

When I do aws configure :

```
`Access Key ID [None]: "ACCESS KEY HERE"`
`AWS Secret Access Key [None]: "SECRET KEY HERE"`
`Default region name [None]: us-east-1`
`Default output format [None]: `
```

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\jiten/.aws/credentials'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and I fixed it by deleting credentials folder and re run aws configure command.

Comment: I need to delete the credentials folder only? I will do and let you know if thats works or not